# PhantomJS/CasperJS AssertExists() is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to check wether a selector exists in my webpage but casperjs never finds it.

I've tried two approaches:

**1. Without waiting**

```
casper.then(function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.test.assertExists('#search-form', 'the element exists');
    // this.test.assertExists('.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus', 'the element exists');
});
```

**2. Waiting for selector**

```
casper.waitForSelector('#search-form', function() {
    this.echo("I'm sure #search-form is available in the DOM");
});
```

**3. Another waiting approach**

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
     return this.evaluate(function() {
         return $('#search-form').length == 1;
     });
 }, function then() {    // step to execute when check() is ok
     test.assertExists('#search-form', 'tabs area is found');
 }, function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
     this.echo("Timeout: page did not load in time...").exit();
 });
```

None of them has been able to find the selector so far. And this selector is loaded from the html, it is not inserted by the javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think you should check if your selector is in your webpage like that :

```
casper.then(function(){
    console.log(this.getPageContent());
});
```

command -pipe the output-: `casperjs test yourFile.js > seePageContent.html`

Or you might prefer this way (with a wait if needed) :

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(3000,function(){
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.write("seePageContent.html", this.getPageContent(), 'w');
    });
});
```

That way you know if your element is present or not. If not, then your previous step is wrong.

Comment: +1 One could think that this might be obsolete, but sometimes a page will have different DOM elements depending on userAgent or broken parsing in either browser or phantomjs.

Comment: You're right, I had one issue where by default CasperJs launched the mobile version of the website **with Linux**. The userAgent was strangely unknown for the device, causing casper to switch in mobile version. I noticed it just by checking the DOM (and confirmed it with `this.capture()`). Marcelosalloum, you can wait for an element to appear, if it's not present, it won't work. It is better to know what is present rather than what is not.