# How can I click this button in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

After some debugging, it appears I'm having difficulty either clicking or triggering the click event of this button within CasperJS:

```
<a id="generate" class="btn" href="#generate"><strong>Generate</strong></a>
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: [
        '...\\JQuery\\jquery-1.11.1.min.js'
    ],
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'
    }
});
casper.on('page.initialized', function (page) {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        (function() {
            window.screen = {
                width: 1600,
                height: 900
            };
            var fake_nav = {};
            for (var i in navigator) {
                fake_nav[i] = navigator[i];
            }
            fake_nav.javaEnabled = function() { return true; };
            fake_nav.language = 'en-US';
            window.navigator = fake_nav;
        })();
    });
});
casper.start('http://www.json-generator.com/', function() {
    this.echo("Loaded successfully.");
});
var template = '[\'{{repeat(1,3)}}\',    {asdf: "hello"}    ]';
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function(input) {
        window.$('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror.setValue(input);
     }, template);
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.$('#generate').click();
    });
});
casper.then(function() {
    var doc = this.evaluate(function($) {
        return window.$('.CodeMirror')[1].CodeMirror.getValue();
    });
    this.echo(doc);
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('All Done.');
    this.exit();
});
```

This generates the output (note the blank line from the "casper.echo(doc)"):

```
Loaded successfully.

All Done.
```

I've confirmed that my javascript works in the browser console in both Chrome and Firefox. Why can't I click this button in CasperJS?

Comment: Try that : `this.click('#generate.btn');`

Comment: ^- This goes outside of `this.evaluate` and inside of `casper.then`. Also, I don't see why `document.$` should be defined when you try to click it. Maybe also try `window.$` or even `$`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I attempted document.$ , window.$ and plain $ - none worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Fanch - That works! Please enter that as an answer so that I can give you credit where credit is due.

Comment: The page might look different in casper in contrast to the browser. You can make sure the button is there see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23612151/1816580).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using the evaluate function and click on your element in the page DOM environment (with jQuery), just use the casper method : `this.click('#generate.btn');`. It's easier.

There is also the [clickLabel()](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel) function.

Answer (score 2):

There are three functions available for clicking an element in CasperJS:

- [`casper.click()`](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/docs/modules/casper.rst#click):

  - Performs a click on the element matching the provided selector expression.
- [`casper.clickLabel()`](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/docs/modules/casper.rst#clicklabel):

  - Clicks on the first DOM element found containing label text.
- [`casper.thenClick()`](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/docs/modules/casper.rst#thenclick):

  - Adds a new navigation step to click a given selector and optionally add a new navigation step in a single operation.